# Best way to mock WCF Client proxy

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, mocking, rhino-mocks

Are there any ways to mock a WCF client proxy using Rhino mocks framework so I have access to the Channel property? I am trying to unit test Proxy.Close() method but as the proxy is constructed using the abstract base class `ClientBase<T>` which has the `ICommunicationObject` interface, my unit test is failing as the internal infrastructure of the class is absent in the mock object. Any good ways with code samples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See an article [hosting-mock-as-wcf-service](http://bronumski.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/hosting-mock-as-wcf-service.html) and related answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10306934/52277

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you could do is create an interface that inherits from the original service interface and `ICommunicationObject`. You could then bind to and mock that interface and still have all the important methods.

For example:

```
public interface IMyProxy : IMyService, ICommunicationObject
{
   // Note that IMyProxy doesn't implement IDisposable. This is because
   // you should almost never actually put a proxy in a using block, 
   // since there are many cases where the proxy can throw in the Dispose() 
   // method, which could swallow exceptions if Dispose() is called in the 
   // context of an exception bubbling up. 
   // This is a general "bug" in WCF that drives me crazy sometimes.
}

public class MyProxy : ClientBase<IMyService>, IMyProxy
{
   // proxy code 

}

public class MyProxyFactory
{
   public virtual IMyProxy CreateProxy()
   {
      // build a proxy, return it cast as an IMyProxy.
      // I'm ignoring all of ClientBase's constructors here
      // to demonstrate how you should return the proxy 
      // after it's created. Your code here will vary according 
      // to your software structure and needs.

      // also note that CreateProxy() is virtual. This is so that 
      // MyProxyFactory can be mocked and the mock can override 
      // CreateProxy. Alternatively, extract an IMyProxyFactory
      // interface and mock that. 
      return new MyProxy(); 
   } 
} 

public class MyClass
{
   public MyProxyFactory ProxyFactory {get;set;}
   public void CallProxy()
   {
       IMyProxy proxy = ProxyFactory.CreateProxy();
       proxy.MyServiceCall();
       proxy.Close();
   }
}


// in your tests; been a while since I used Rhino  
// (I use moq now) but IIRC...:
var mocks = new MockRepository();
var proxyMock = mocks.DynamicMock<IMyProxy>();
var factoryMock = mocks.DynamicMock<MyProxyFactory>();
Expect.Call(factoryMock.CreateProxy).Return(proxyMock.Instance);
Expect.Call(proxyMock.MyServiceCall());
mocks.ReplayAll();

var testClass = new MyClass();
testClass.ProxyFactory = factoryMock.Instance;
testClass.CallProxy();

mocks.VerifyAll();
```